# How can I see at which index my iterator is?

Tags: python, iterator

So I have a string `source`, over which I loop with an iterator:

```
iterator = iter(source)
for char in iterator:
  do stuff
```

However, now say that I have a check in `do stuff`, where I compare the value of the iterator to 'h'. Then I want to see if the 'h' is followed by "ello ", in some way, and add the first ten characters after that to a list.
For this my own idea would be to find out which index corresponds with the current position of the iterator, so that I can say:

```
indIt = index(char)
if source[indIt + 1: indIt + 6] == "ello ":
  someList.append(source[indIt + 7:indIt + 16])
  indIt += 17
  char = indIt #which may also be fun to know how it can be done, if
```

This would mean that for given input `hello Sandra, oh and hello Oscar, i welcome you both!`, `someList` would contain ["Sandra, oh", "Oscar, i w"].

So can I, in some way, figure out to which index the current position of an iterator corresponds?

Comment: Use `enumerate`.

Comment: There is no such function.

Comment: @ppperry: What's wrong with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html)?

Comment: @ppperry: yes there is, what makes you think there is not?

Comment: this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterators don't expose an index, because there doesn't have to be a *sequence* underlying one.

Use the `enumerate()` function to add one to your iteration:

```
for index, char in enumerate(iterator):
```

Now iteration produces `(index, value)` tuples, which you can assign to two separate variables using tuple assignment.